# Change datetime picker output format

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

How to change datetime picker output format for a specific format? I need change the format of the following selecteddate variable to "dd/M/yyyy" without converting to String and converting back to Datetime using DataTimeParse. Is there any method to change DateTime picker default picking format to "dd/M/yyyy" to instead of "MM/dd/yyyy". I've tried with picker properties->Custom Format but it doesn't work.

```
DateTime selecteddate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

Comment: What are you programming? WPF, ASP.Net, WinForms, Xamarin, Blazor?

Comment: Hi @PaulSinnema It's Winforms

Comment: Add that to your tags please.

Comment: Hi, @PaulSinnema it's already added

Comment: Are you talking about what the control displays in the UI or what you get from the `Value` property?

Comment: Hi @user18387401 I need to change Value property

Comment: No you don't. It doesn't have a format. See my answer.

Comment: How EXACTLY are you viewing that value? I'm in Australia and I just looked at a `DateTime` value in the debugger and it was displayed using my regional settings, so d/MM/yyyy. Where exactly do you think you're seeing something you shouldn't? Again, the value doesn't have a format so it doesn't matter from that perspective.

Comment: For me its MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: That's still irrelevant. It would obviously be nice to see the values in your preferred format but that's a matter of configuring Windows and Visual Studio appropriately. It has nothing to do with your code and `DateTime` values still have no format. You are trying to fix the wrong problem. Give us all the relevant information and we will help you fix the right problem.

Comment: @user18387401 I will edit the full question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom format in 2 parameters like so:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```